# Origen de la expresión "tener más moral que el Alcoyano"

Tags: españa, modismos, expresiones

Cuando alguien no se da por vencido y sigue insistiendo a veces en España se dice *tienes más moral que el Alcoyano*.

*Alcoyano* es el gentilicio de Alcoy (provincia de Alicante), pero ¿cúal es el origen de está expresión?

Comment: También he escuchado la versión "tener más fé que el Alcoyano"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se refiere al [C. D. Alcoyano](http://www.cdalcoyano.com/), equipo de fútbol de la ciudad española que indicas. Hay [dos teorías sobre el origen](http://www.abc.es/20121031/deportes-futbol/abci-leyenda-moral-alcoyano-201210301643.html) de la expresión.

La primera dice que en un partido de Copa, el árbitro, un minuto antes de tiempo, pitó el final del partido, y los del Alcoyano  se lo recriminaron porque creían que era posible remontar pese a que iban perdiendo por goleada:

> Hay quien dice que la leyenda se gestó en 1948 durante un partido de Copa cuando el conjunto de Alcoy caía goleado. Según esta tesis, el árbitro dio por finalizado el encuentro a falta de un minuto y los jugadores corrieron hacia él para pedirle que se disputaran los 60 segundos que restaban. Mantenían la moral y confiaban ciegamente en una remontada imposible.

La segunda teoría dice que en un partido de Liga iban perdiendo por goleada y todavía tenían moral y ánimo para seguir jugando porque pensaban que podrían remontar y ganar:

> Otros se apuntan a la teoría de que la leyenda tiene su origen en un partido de Liga cuando el Alcoyano militaba en Tercera división. Perdía por 13-0 y sus futbolistas no paraban de darse ánimos en la creencia de que la victoria todavía era posible.

Comment: +1 por las interesantes teorías/orígenes de esta expresión.

Comment: El 21 de enero del 2021 Alcoyano elimina al Real Madrid con un jugador menos en la prórroga con un gol de Juanan, en el minuto 115. Es uno de los héroes en una noche histórica para el club alicantino. Zidane, el entrenador de la tres Champions y los 19 títulos, se queda sin la Copa del Rey. Al final, lo consiguieron.

Answer (score 2):

Se refiere al [equipo de fútbol de Alcoy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_Deportivo_Alcoyano). No sé mucho de fútbol, pero parece que, a pesar de perder constantemente, el equipo siempre aparece en las quinielas, tiene la moral alta y está dispuesto a jugar otro partido contra un nuevo rival.

Espero que ayude.